# Google Cloud Text-to-Speech to read output data file and output the speech in media player through Node.js API

Tags: node.js, audio, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am trying to create a text to speech audio file using Google texttospeech Wavenet voices.

At the same time I want the device speakers to output the speech.

In other words, as the mp3 file is being generated the device should output the audio.
I've tried various combinations of effectsProfileId in audioConfig but nothing seems to work

The following code creates an mp3 file. But there's no audio output. Everything works fine except there is no sound from the device speakers as the mp3 file is being generated.

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

//Some text
const text1 = 'The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plain';

//define path to output mp3 file
const outputFile = './audiofiles/sample1.mp3';

//set environment variable
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "./key/runningzebra-7d04161f3149.json";


//define a voice
const voice1 = {
  languageCode:"en-US",
  ssmlGender:"MALE",
  name:"en-US-Wavenet-B"
}

//Define an audioConfig
//This should generate audio output on the device speakers
//But that is not working
const audioConfig1 = {
  effectsProfileId: ["headphone-class-device", "large-automotive-class-device", "telephony-class-application"],
  pitch: -10.0,
  speakingRate: 0.75,
  audioEncoding: "MP3"
}

const input1 = {
  text:text1
}

//Define a request
const request = {
  input:input1, voice:voice1, audioConfig:audioConfig1
}

async function getAudio(request, outputFile) {
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    await writeFile(outputFile, response.audioContent, 'binary');
    console.log(`Audio content written to file: ${outputFile}`);
}



getAudio(request, outputFile);
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Do you want to play the output audio file after the text-to-speech conversion, or are you trying to play the audio file in real-time during the conversion?

Comment: Hi Vishal K. I wanted to do it in real-time. However my next issue is how to do read an audio file and produce sound. So I guess the short answer is I'd like to know how to do both.

Comment: Hi @user3567761, If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do real-time conversion using the Cloud Text-to-Speech API. Because it gives a playable audio file as an output. However,  you can play the converted audio file once it gets downloaded after the execution of code. I have tested your non-real-time requirement in Linux by altering your code, and I was able to read and play the converted audio file. Before executing the code, please install the below packages first:

- Install the [Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org/download) package by executing the below command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install audacious
```

- Install [play-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound) package by executing the below command in the terminal.

```
npm install play-sound
```

Try below code:

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

//Some text
const text1 = 'The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plain.';

//define path to output mp3 file
const outputFile = 'sample1.mp3';

//set environment variable
//process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "./Composer/key.json";

//define a voice
const voice1 = {
 languageCode:"en-US",
 ssmlGender:"MALE",
 name:"en-US-Wavenet-B"
}

//Define an audioConfig
//This should generate audio output on the device speakers
//But that is not working
const audioConfig1 = {
 effectsProfileId: ["headphone-class-device", "large-automotive-class-device", "telephony-class-application"],
 pitch: -10.0,
 speakingRate: 0.75,
 audioEncoding: "MP3"
}

const input1 = {
 text:text1
}

//Define a request
const request = {
 input:input1, voice:voice1, audioConfig:audioConfig1
}

async function getAudio(request, outputFile) {
   const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
   const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
   await writeFile(outputFile, response.audioContent, 'binary');
   console.log(`Audio content written to file: ${outputFile}`);
}

getAudio(request, outputFile);


//play-sound is used for to play the audio file
//I have passed “audacious” as a player for play sound. You can also pass other media players into this. 
var player = require('play-sound')({player:"audacious"}) 

player.play(outputFile, function (err) {  
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Audio finished");
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Vishal K. I'd kind of given up on getting a response so I never checked back. Yes that works. Thanks

Comment: Had some problems with audacious. sound-play worked well. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/sound-play

Worked best using absolute rather than a relative path